# RoR, Can't iterate from DateTime/TimeWithZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, seeding

I have a simple task where I want to take a starting date and an ending date and loop over the days/dates.  This code is being used in my db:seed rake task.  Currently, my code has gone through the following attempts.

```
(someModel.start_date.to_datetime..someModel.end_date.to_datetime).each { 
    |x| puts x 
}
 ......
(someModel.start_date...someModel.end_date).each { |x| puts x }
```

In each case, I get an error like this.

```
can't iterate from ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
or 
can't iterate from DateTime
```

If anyone has any clue on how to iterate over a range of DateTimes I'd be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
start = someModel.start_date.to_datetime
finish = someModel.end_date.to_datetime
while(start < finish) do
  #bunch of awesome stuff
  start += 1.day
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris.  I had to struggle a little bit then I read that Dates are immutable and I was on my way.

Comment: You got it dude. Best of luck.

Answer (score 12):

You must make sure that you are dealing with a `Date` object (by calling `to_date`), then everything works as expected:

```
start_date.to_date.upto(end_date.to_date) {|date| puts date }
```

Or with a range:

```
(start_date.to_date..end_date.to_date).to_a
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't iterate from `DateTime`. But you can iterate when start and end of
interval are instances of `Date`. Convert them if possible.

And then look at these `Date` methods:

- [step()](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/step)
- [upto()](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Date/upto)
- [downto()](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Date/downto)

to use instead of `each`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate on the range you might consider a loop and step each day using something like `someModel.start_date + 1.day.to_i`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we're doing to iterate by minutes over two TimeWithZones:

```
  # allow iteration over a set of TimeWithZones
  def self.time_map(range, step: 30.minutes, &block)
    result = []
    time = range.first
    max = range.last
    test = range.exclude_end? ? ->(t) { t < max } : ->(t) { t <= max }
    value = block_given? ? ->(t) { yield(t) } : ->(t) { t }
    while test.call(time) do
      result << value.call(time)
      time += step
    end
    result
  end
```